# Why is debug flag in GCC abbreviated "g"?

Tags: gcc, history, language

In GCC the debug flag is "-g". I have not been able to find why "g" was chosen for this. Does anyone know?

Comment: `gcc` did choose `-g`, because that option was already used to add the symbol table to the output, so the question should be why `-g` was originally chosen for C compilers.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` did not invent that. It just copied that from other compilers¹.

I suspect this goes back to the Amsterdam Compiler Kit, which already had `-g`, but at least as far as I'm aware, the reasoning for calling it `g` was never announced publicly.

I mean, this was early 1980s, CPUs were slow, RAM was sparse, and things were generally not a pleasure to type (remember, we're not talking about computers with arbitrary graphics screens and the ability to scroll the window without any overhead) if things became wider than a couple dozens of columns. Therefore, basically all flags were single-character by convention.

If you only have the English alphabet to choose from, you quickly end up doing things like "this letter is unused, OK, use that".

I don't think there's much reasoning there.

---

(as far as I'm aware, POSIX pre-2001 does not specify C compiler flags, but POSIX 2001 does specify that the c99 compiler has `-g` for debug information. That is at least a hint that more than one UNIXoid tradition supplied `-g`; I'm, however, not versed enough in late-1970's UNIXes to say which other compilers to look at.)

Comment: It’s present in [V8 `cc`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/cc), perhaps introduced in a V7 derivative somewhere (such as [4.2BSD](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.2BSD/usr/man/man1/cc.1)).

Comment: @StephenKitt ah, V7, that would place things ~ 1979. I tried to get an early pcc manual, but failed, but at least the Plan9 man page contains no reference to `-g`, and considering the state of computing I suspect for the era, it's unlikely that K&R's original C compiler had "debug symbols", so if V7's `cc` indeed had that flag, that'd be the original place, probably. It's a bit hard to narrow things down – ACK and the development of V8 happened in parallel, in the end.

Comment: It wasn’t in V7, it was in V8. I think it appeared with `sdb` in 32V ([`man sdb`](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=32V/usr/man/man1/sdb.1) mentions it).

Comment: I think it's based on generate debug information.

Comment: @K-attila- that might well be the case, but I honestly don't think it is – it's just the "debug" flag. You'll notice that at least glibc, the standard solaris libc etc still ship a `libg.a` (which is the debug build of the respective libc). That is *not* just a libc with **g**enerated debug symbols, but actually a different build of the libc containing additional debug functionality enabled. (look for example at the C8 `cc` man page that Stephen links to above – it mentions `-lg` as option to the linker)

Comment: @K-attila- if we're guessing here, *my* guess would be that someone wanted a "**d**ebug" flag, but `-D` already existed and was very commonly used, so lowercase `-d` would have led to lots of confusion. So, they went simply with the other end of the word "debu**g**" and introduced `-g`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yep :) **g**enerate debu**g**... And yes, I'm not sure.

Comment: @K-attila- but, *debug* appears in all the old man pages, *generate* doesn't. I think "generate" is a good way to *remember* `-g`, but it's very unlikely the reason, imho. And honestly, all a compiler does is *generate things*: preprocessed code, ASTs, machine code, linker tables…; it's not clear why *debug symbols* would be the one thing that gets the flag for "generate".

Comment: This inspired me : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=msvc-170 (and the xenix....)

Comment: but that's the intel/Digital Research/Microsoft/Borland tradition of compilers, pretty unrelated